# Find a word and get the url from the following href

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have:

```
var text = '<p class="bla">blablabla<a href="/blabla">blabla</a></p><p class="class2">blablabla<a href="/blabla">blabla</a></p>';
```

How can I get the first URL that follows the class `bla`?

Sorry forgot to mention that I am using that on the server side with node.js. So I basically have the HTML as a string to use within nodejs. Perhaps regex?

Comment: It looks like you want to get the link that is a child of an element with class `bla`?

Comment: Right. I just added that I am using it within node.js.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom.

Comment: Then you'll have to use a [library](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml) or use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex, please. :)

HTML is not a regular language, so you have to use an HTML parser instead. [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) is recommended since it's fastest one. This should do it:

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2")

var seen_bla = false
var result

var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
  onopentag: function(name, attribs){
     if (attribs.class === 'bla') {
        seen_bla = true
     }
     if (name === 'a' && seen_bla && result == null) {
        result = attribs.href
     }
  },
  onend: function() {
     console.log(result)
  }
})

parser.write('<p class="bla">blablabla<a href="/blabla">blabla</a></p><p class="class2">blablabla<a href="/blabla">blabla</a></p>')
parser.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the first element with the `bla` class, try

```
var text = '<p class="bla">blablabla<a href="/blabla">blabla</a></p><p>class="class2">blablabla<a href="/blabla">blabla</a></p>'
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
console.log(doc.getElementsByClassName('bla')[0].getElementsById('a')[0].href);
```

PS:  I wrapped the code in that variable in quotes.